# Transitioning view in TabBarController interrupts touchesMoved

Tags: ios, swift, touchesmoved, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I seem to be having some trouble with the following setup:

- I have a subclass of a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` (`import
  UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass`) in order to override
  `touchesMoved`.
- I have a button that contains an object of this
  GestureRecognizer subclass, which calls a selector.
- The method called by this selector contains a callback to be called by the original GestureRecognizer subclass every time `touchesMoved` is called.

So when I longPress on the button, and then move my finger around, the callback is called multiple times and I can view the properties of the touches, like the number, for example. (`touches.count`)

I am trying to transition view controllers of a TabBarController based on touches information, but when I implement this, (either through `selectedIndex =` or `UIView.transitionFromView()`)  the callback is only called at the beginning of the longPressEvent. (i.e. only once, and not multiple times.) I am not sure why this happens. Since the button is in the TabBarController, it should not be affected by transitioning views.

Here is some of the relevant code:

The GestureRecognizer subclass:

```
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class LongPressGestureRecongnizerSubclass: UILongPressGestureRecognizer{
    var detectTouchesMoved = false
    var toCallWhenTouchesMoved: ((touches: Set<UITouch>) -> ())?
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if detectTouchesMoved{
            toCallWhenTouchesMoved?(touches: touches)
        } 

    }
}
```

The delegate method called when a longPress is recognized.

```
func centerButtonLongPressed(tabBarView: TabBarView!){
    for gestureRecognizer in tabBarView.centerButton.gestureRecognizers!{
        if let longPressGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? LongPressGestureRecongnizerSubclass{
            longPressGestureRecognizer.detectTouchesMoved = true
            longPressGestureRecognizer.toCallWhenTouchesMoved = ({(touches: Set<UITouch>) -> (Void) in
                //Here I can view touches properties every time touchesMoved() is called, but not when I try to transition view here.
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I realized that the problem is that since the transition is being called synchronously, it messes with `touchesMoved()`. When I move the transition method off the UI thread, the following error is thrown:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes. This will cause an exception in a future release.

How can I prevent the slow, synchronous code of the transition from messing with the `touchesMoved()`?

How can I get achieve what I am envisioning? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there was no issue with the animation interrupting the touches. Touches were being canceled because I was improperly using a custom UITabBarController, `FoldingTabBar`, which can be found [here](https://github.com/Yalantis/FoldingTabBar.iOS/tree/master/FoldingTabBar)